# Analytic geometry textbook introduction.

Tags: reference-request, analytic-geometry

I need the help of others concerning a good-rigorous analytic geometry textbook. (high school level.)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is this even a thing?  Usually analytic geometry is covered in the same course as other topics (e.g. algebra, Euclidean geometry, trigonometry, logarithms, complex numbers, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you said something about your background and your goals. For now, you might consider looking at any of the hundreds of freely available analytic geometry texts in google-books. Here are three widely used texts from the early 20th century:

[**New Analytic Geometry**](http://books.google.com/books?id=URs3AAAAMAAJ) by Percey Franklyn Smith and Arthur Sullivan Gale (1912)

[**Analytic Geometry**](http://books.google.com/books?id=oo86AAAAMAAJ) by Maria M. Roberts and Julia Trueman Colpitts (1918)

[**Plane and Solid Analytic Geometry**](http://books.google.com/books?id=xjcNAAAAYAAJ) by William Fogg Osgood and William Caspar Graustein (1921)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some references you may try

$1.~~~~$ "Calculus with Analytical Geometry" by G. F. Simmons

$2.~~~~$ "Calculus & Analytical Geometry: Single Variable Version" by G. B. Thomas

$3.~~~~$ "Analytical Solid Geometry" by Shanti Narayan and P.K. Mittal