# Analytic geometry book

Tags: reference-request, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a good book in analytic geometry which deals with line, hyperplanes, spheres, etc. in a vector perspective. Are there some standards references?

Thanks

Comment: Based on looking at your top tags this request seems odd.  You know that analytic geometry generally just refers to high school coordinate geometry, right?  P.S. I'm not the one that downvoted.

Comment: @Bye_World In my country we study vector analytic geometry just at university. The analytic geometry at high school here doesn't deal with vectors.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6521.pdf

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644246/analytic-geometry-textbook-introduction).  As are [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425371/deducing-formulas-of-analytic-geometry) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165852/a-good-open-source-book-on-analytic-geometry?rq=1).

Comment: @Bye_World gave links to other questions where I gave a lot of references. However, those references are mainly at the high school and early college level. If you're looking for something a little more advanced, consider [**Multidimensional Analytic Geometry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0032OW6PI) by Karol Borsuk (1969), which I've previously cited [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633826/books-on-geometric-transformations-and-or-analytic-geometry).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Interesting.  I didn't even know there *were* books on advanced analytic geometry.  (At the risk of seeing a trend in only two data points) Based on your recommendation and mle's, it looks like they may tend to all come out of Russia/ Slavic countries.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The following books might be of interest. In order to get an idea of the detailed content, I am linking the TOC:

- Ralph Palmer Agnew: Analytic Geometry and Calculus, with Vectors ([TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyP2D.png))
- P. R. Vittal: Analytical Geometry. 2D and 3D. ([TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8DmZ.png))
- G. B. Thomas and R. L. Finney: Calculus and Analytical Geometry ([TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD4C4.jpg))
- E. W. Swokowski: Calculus with Analytic Geometry ([TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYkcS.png))

You may be interested in taking a look into these free PDFs:

- [Ruslan A. Sharipov: Course of Analytical Geometry (arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6521.pdf)
- [Friedan and Shenker: The analytic geometry of two-dimensional conformal field theory](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pages/friedan/papers/Nucl_Phys_B281_509_1987.pdf) (this may be too far away from the desired topic)
- [Robert-Ellis: Calculus with Analytic Geometry](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Robert-Ellis-25/publication/44500439_Calculus_with_analytic_geometry_Robert_Ellis_Denny_Gulick/links/0a85e539dfed13e394000000/Calculus-with-analytic-geometry-Robert-Ellis-Denny-Gulick.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

*Lekcii po analitičeskoj geometrii* by P.S. Alexandrov is probably the standard textbook in Russian.

Comment: Is there some translation available?

Comment: I don't know of any.